# Created login but when redirect doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql

I created a login page login.php, when the user logs in they are redirected to login-home.php, I then,

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
echo "Welcome to the member's area, " . $_SESSION['username'] . "!";
} else {
echo "Please log in first to see this page.";
}
```

and i get the the Please log in first.

Why wont this actually log in?

Login.php

```
 <?PHP
 error_reporting(9);

 require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");
 if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
 {
$users['admin'] = array('password' => 'admin', 'redirect' => 'admin.php');
$users[$username] = array('password' => $password, 'redirect' => 'login-home.php');

if(array_key_exists($_POST['username'],$users)) {
if($_POST['password'] == $users[$_POST['username']]['password']) {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
    header('Location:'.$users[$_POST['username']]['redirect']);
    exit();
 }
}
 if($fgmembersite->Login())
 {
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login-home.php");
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: you should post your logincode

Comment: in the first snip you're using "loggedin" as key, and "loggedIn" in the second one. Isn't php case sensitive?

Answer (score 2):

With logging in and using sessions,  Make sure that you are using `session_start()` on any page that is using the `$_SESSION` var.  Check out the [php session manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) for some more information on this.

With redirects,  Im not sure if you are having a problem with this or not, but you need to make sure that there is nothing written to the browser before a redirect.  a empty line before the redirect outside of the `<?php` will even cuase a redirect to not work.  Any kind of echo or print will also cause this.

**UPDATE**

After seeing your code,  This shows that you are not doing a `session_start()`  See code below:

```
 <?PHP
 session_start();
 error_reporting(9);

 require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");
 if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
 {
$users['admin'] = array('password' => 'admin', 'redirect' => 'admin.php');
$users[$username] = array('password' => $password, 'redirect' => 'login-home.php');

if(array_key_exists($_POST['username'],$users)) {
if($_POST['password'] == $users[$_POST['username']]['password']) {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
    header('Location:'.$users[$_POST['username']]['redirect']);
    exit();
 }
}
 if($fgmembersite->Login())
 {
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login-home.php");
 }
}
?>
```

Then on your login-home.php page before anything is checked with sessions, put `session_start()`.  Once a user logs out, you will want to do the following

```
session_start();
session_unset();
header('Location:url/to/redirect/to');
```

Comment: session_unset — Free all session variables.  basically it will clear out the $_SESSION variables and make them undefined

Comment: Also, when i put just select * from user, everyones information comes up, not the user that is logged in

Comment: what does that have to do with your question?

Comment: if a user is logged in, isnt it only suposed to pull that users information. That is why I do not believe it is working. i still get the error, please log in

Comment: You need to change your sql to `SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='the user id for user logged in'`   OR change it to `SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='the username for user logged in'`  It looks like maybe you are doing a select * from users before any user logs in within membersite_config.php  if this is the case, this is not a good way to do it.  I would check to see if the username exists, Then if it is does check and see if the password is correct,  THEN and only then select all information for that one user.

Comment: do I really paste this in? SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='the user id for user logged in'

Comment: Please look at this tutorial. http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html  I am not going to write out your entire login script for you.  Ive looked at your history of questions.  so far they have all been about this.  Stackoverflow is not here for you to get people to write code.   If you have looked at this tutorial and still have questions, please come back here

Comment: Im pretty sure i created all my code. I need help finding out what i did wrong. Getting a second opinion hoping someone can see something I didn't.

Comment: Please post what you have in your membersite_config.php file.  What is in your $users array?  why are you doing array_key_exists in it for a username?  Where do you actually do the login checks to see if the user has the correct password.

Comment: All that is in membersite_config is the database login information. hostname: localhost, username:megan, password: megan, database name: megan, table name:user. I check the password in the login page, where i have the redirect. It will check the usernames and passwords in my array

Comment: I also can not get that tutorial to work, It wont go to the success page